# Ignoring weffc++ initialization list order warning for specific code

Tags: c++, initializer-list, weffc++

I have below code:

```
class Base {
    // Some code
    Base(int y) {}
}

class Derived : Base {
       int test;
       Derived(int x);
 }

 Derived::Derived(int x) : Base(x)     {
       // Some code and calculation to generate vale of test
       test = val;
  }
```

I am compiling with flag '-Weffc++'.
And I get warning 'test need to be initialize in initialization list.'
But I can't do that as I need to do few calculation to generate value of test.

So to avoid this error I did try '-Wno-reorder' flag but it did not work. Also I don't prefer it, as it will disable this warning for all the code, I just want to disable this warning for this specific case.

I also did it using '#pragma GCC diagnostic ignore -Weffc++' placed just before constructor in cpp file and it did work. But I need to add pragma to all the constructors where I want to avoid this warning.

But is there any better way to avoid Weffc++ initialization list order warning for specific code. Or is there way to fix this warning?

Comment: "But I can't do that as I need to do few calculation to generate value of test" - You can still do it: `test([]{ /* calculations here */; returrn result;}())`

Comment: There not just calculation I need to connect with some external libraries and few initialization code also to generate value so putting this whole code there will not be a good idea also there are few more variables which uses same code for initialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
Derived::Derived(int x) : Base{ x }, test{} // shut up the compiler.
{
    // Some code and calculation to generate vale of test
    test = val;
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried it but it doesn't look good where we have code initializing same veriable for two times.

Comment: @User7723337 The initializer list ist the only opportunity to initialize something (hence the name ^^) everything after that is assignment.